# Rails3 - Nested resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest

How to use nested resources

Error:

```
No route matches {:controller=>"documents"}
```

Code:

```
<%= link_to "Documentos", school_documents_path(@school)
```

Routes:

```
resources :schools do
   resources :documents, :only => [:index]
   resources :tasks, :only => [:index]
end
```

DocumentsController:

```
class DocumentsController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end
end
```

What is the error?

Comment: your code looks alright. As far as I can see, it should work. What does `rake routes` say? And are you absolutely sure that the error occurs on the line you say it does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restart application :)

Answer (score 0):

this might be a typo but are you missing the `end` from your index method?

Comment: It seems I just needed to restart the rails app. :)